# Executing external process from Java security

Tags: java

What are the security implications of executing external processes using Java ProcessBuilder/Process? For example:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("processExecutable");
InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
int c;
while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
  System.out.print((char) c);
}
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

From what I understood, communication between Java and external processes is via pipes, so I am interested how difficult it is for someone to eavesdrop and get data sent from a process back to Java on Unix? Will only users logged in to the same machine have the potential to eavesdrop? Will any logged user have the potential or only administrators or users in the same group etc. as user running the Java app which executed the external process?

Comment: Something to be aware of is that the command line is usually public (on Linux at least). This could be a problem if you invoke the executable with a password on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The pipes can be accessed via /proc//fd/.  This means that under a default configuration, only root and the process owner can open them.  Therefore, you can consider the pipe to be as safe as the local filesystem.